# AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) timeout length by browser

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've been scouring the web trying to find a straight answer to this. Does anyone know the default timeout lengths for ajax request by browser? Also by version if it's changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think browsers have a timeout for AJAX, there is only synchronous or asynchronous requests; synchronous - first freezes the JavaScript execution until the request returns,
asynchronous - does not freeze JavaScript execution, it simply takes the request out of the execution flow, and if you have a callback function it will execute the the function in parallel with the running scripts (similar to a thread)

```
**sync flow:**

running JS script
     |
    ajax
(wait for response)
     |
execute callback 
     |
running JS script




 **async flow:**

 running JS script
     |
    ajax  --------------------
     |                       |
 running JS script       execute callback
```

Comment: Chrome does seem to have a timeout. Even if I set an ajax call timeout to 900000 (15 minutes), the requests times out after exactly 1 minute with status 'canceled' on a long running request.

Comment: M87's answer on this thread also confirms this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798882/is-there-any-maximum-minimum-timeout-for-the-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 22):

According to the specs, the timeout value defaults to zero, which means there is no timeout. However, you can set a timeout value on the XHR.timeout property; the value is in milliseconds.

Sources:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20110816/#the-timeout-attribute
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But there is an underlying timeout which is not covered by the spec. From the second link: `If you set an XMLHttpRequest time-out value that is larger than the network stack's time-out value, the network stack will time out first and the ontimeout event will not be raised.`

Answer (score 3):

I did a modest amount of testing. To test I loaded my website, stopped the local server and then attempted an AJAX request. I set the `timeout` to something low like 1000ms until I could ensure I had minimal code (you *must* put the `xhr.timeout` after `open` and *before* `send`).

Once I got it working my initial goal was to determine the appropriate amount of time to allow however I was surprised how quickly the `timeout` would be outright ignored by browsers. My goal reformed in to trying to determine what the maximum timeout *could* be before error handling was no longer viable.That means past these fairly short spans of time your timeout handler script *will not work at all*. What I found was pretty pathetic.

- Chrome 60: 995ms, 996ms will throw a dirty evil error in to the console.
- Firefox 52 ESR: ~3000ms, position of mouse or other issue may cause no response around or just under three seconds.

So...

```
xhr.open(method,url,true);
xhr.timeout = 995;//REALLY short
xhr.send(null);
xhr.ontimeout = function ()
{
 //Code will only execute if at or below *effective* timeouts list above.
 //Good spot to make a second attempt.
}
```

So if your `timeout` is set higher than 995ms **Chrome** will ignore your code and puke on your nice clean empty console that you worked hard to keep clean. **Firefox** is not much better and there are unreliable requests that just timeout for well beyond any patience I have and in doing so ignore the `ontimeout` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Browser does have a timeout value, behavior depends upon browser chrome has timeout value of 5 minutes and after 5 minutes it does resend ajax call

Comment: Mine timeouts after 10 seconds..?