# Is there any maximum/minimum timeout for the xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Is there any maximum timeout for the xmlhttprequest ? Currently its not possible to set timeout value more than 1 minute in chrome.
  let xmlHttpRequest: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttpRequest.timeout = 120000;

Comment: what happens if you do

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a maximum timeout for `xmlhttprequest` in chrome, and that is 1 minute. Unfortunately you can not increase the timeout by setting the `timeout` property of `xmlhttprequest` in chrome. But if you are on windows, you might possibly set the maixmum tmeout with the help of `regedit`, and the steps are ...

- press `window + r` > type `regedit` > press `enter`
- navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings`
- create a `DWORD` vale named `KeepAliveTimeout` and set the data value `120000` (2 min.)
- create another value named `ServerInfoTimeout`, following the same steps
- restart PC

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can we modify the timeout value from the client side itself using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

No, the XMLHttpRequest object does not have a maximum timeout value, because the default timeout value is 0, meaning infinite.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout

You mentioned Chrome: the network stack you are on **does** have timeout limitations.

Google Chrome will not let you change the default timeout values.