# xhr timeout gives invalid state error in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Am trying to set timeout in XMLHttpRequest but it shows `invalid state error`, here's the code

```
function get(url, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // headers
    if (options && options.headers) {
      for (let header in options.headers) {
        if (options.headers.hasOwnProperty(header)) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header, options.headers[header]);
        }
      }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    // FIXME: Why is IE11 failing on "xhr.timeout?
    // xhr.timeout = 10000;

    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        try {
          const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          resolve(data);
        } catch (ex) {
          reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText
          });
        }
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };

    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}

export default { get };
```

[image]

I had a look at following links [link1](https://github.com/stephanebachelier/superapi/issues/5) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760635/why-does-setting-xmlhttprequest-responsetype-before-calling-open-throw) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502410/ajax-xmlhttprequest-timeout-length-by-browser) and specifically kept `xhr.timeout` between `xhr.open` and `xhr.send`

I even tried this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState == 1 ) {
    xhr.timeout = 5000;
  }
};
```

But no luck

Comment: About your FIXME comment: [@Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) is a note about it.

Answer (score 7):

Add `xhr.timeout` after the `xhr.open` method.

Comment: absolutely. It is documented : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout#Compatibilit%C3%A9_des_navigateurs

Answer (score 1):

You should set `xhr.timeout` only when you call `xhr.open()` in **asynchronous** mode, otherwise `MSIE` will rise an exception `INVALID_STATE_ERR`.

Example:
xhr.open("POST", url, true);

ps. Strangely, i don't see this issue in FF & Chrome.